# SBS2011 Exchange 2010 reassign mailbox to another

Tags: exchange-2010, windows-sbs-2011

Have a user (Bosslady) with multiple mailboxes; she@domain.co, things@domain.com, accounts@domain.com etc
We need to "move/reassign/relocate" accounts@domain.com from BossLady to Accountant.
I looked at this approach, but wasn't sure if I would break something:
Remove accounts@domain.com entry from EMC / Recipient Configuration / Mailbox / BossLady / Properties / Email Addresses
Add accounts@domain.com entry to ~ / Accountant / Properties / Email Addresses

Will this approach work without losing/breaking anything?

Thanks for any advice.
TerryF

Comment: What type of mailbox is it? Are you sure we are talking about an actual mailbox and not an alias? Typically users have a primary mailbox and then they are connected to additional shared mailboxes by granting permissions. In this case you would just remove permissions for the shared box for one person and add permissions for the other person. If it’s just an alias then doing what you described will work. If its an actual mailbox we’re talking about then it is more involved like I described.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding, just been buried in dramas.    I was able to move the mailbox from one user to another.  - Terry

Answer (score 0):

What did you mean by moving the mailbox?

If the Bosslady has multiple mailboxes, just assign the full access mailbox permission to the Accountant, you don't need to configure the email address.

Comment: Tks for coming back; I was able to just move the mailbox to the accounts mailbox's list. Works Ok.